# gwt & gwt-incubator-security

Tags: gwt, spring-security

Can anybody  give me a hint about how to implement Spring Security using gwt-incubator-security and AOP? I tried to do everything as described on their wiki pages, but still no effect. I'm interested in how to make PRC calls secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no direct examples for you but here are some resources that might be helpfull:

This blog post writes about Technical tips Using Acegi (now Spring Security) with GWT:
http://www.dotnetguru2.org/bmarchesson/index.php/2007/04/23/technical_tip_using_acegi_with_gwt

And this group page has a overview on GWT security issues and what you can do about them. It has a specific sectino on how to make RPC more secure: **Part 2**, section **XSRF and GWT** under **Protecting Your Application**: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/web/security-for-gwt-applications